Возможно ли ботом, используя business_connection_id из группового чата написать в личные?
Исходные: Есть Телеграм бизнес-аккаунт. Есть группа в Телеграм. Python -> aiogram
Возможно ли ботом, который админ в группе и видит все сообщения и всех пользователей, используя business_connection_id написать в личные от имени бизнес-аккаунта пользователю, который что-то написал в группе?
Уточню вопрос: Хочу, чтобы бот мог написать заготовленное сообщение в личку любому участнику группы используя его ID. Пользователь соответственно бота не запускал никогда, поэтому от имени бота напрямую написать не возможно.
Используя business_connection_id можно отправить пользователю заготовленное сообщение, если пользователь написал в личку бизнес-аккаунту, а вот если пользователь написал в группу, то отправить ему заготовленное сообщение не получается. Возможно ли такое решение? Подскажите куда копать? Вот коды с которыми я воюю:
Код 1: Когда пользователь в группе пишет "bb" срабатывает функция которая отрабатывает всё без ошибок
@router.message(F.text == 'bb')
async def command_start_handler(message: types.Message) -> None:
    telegram_id = message.from_user.id #telegram_id = message.chat.id
    ch_id = message.chat.id  # id группы
    username = message.from_user.username
    await message.answer(f'Hello, {ch_id}')  # визуальный тест переменной
    await bot.send_message(chat_id = 58*****62, text = 'Оповещение') # Оповещение конкретному пользователю (админу)
    await add_to_database(telegram_id, ch_id, username) # занесение в базу данных нужные параметры

Код 2: Этим кодом бот пытается отправить заготовленное сообщение в личку пользователю, который в группе написал "11". Но эта функция не срабатывает в группе. Игнорируется полностью. Но без ошибок работает, если пользователь пишет в личку бизнес-аккаунту. Бот присылает заготовленный текст от имени не бота, а аккаунта, даже если бот у пользователя заблокирован
@router.business_message(F.text == '11')
async def business_handler_message(message: types.Message):
  await message.answer(f'Hello, {message.chat.id}')  # визуальный тест переменной
  print('Функция в работе')
  print(message.business_connection_id)
   try:
     await bot.send_message(business_connection_id=message.business_connection_id,
                           chat_id=message.from_user.id, text='Бот1 - Ответ от имени человека')
   except Exception as e:
        print(f'Не удалось ответить на сообщение в ЛС\n Ошибка - {e}')

